# How to concatenate variable with Curl code Php

Tags: php, json, curl

I want to cocatenate variable in curl code,How can i do this ?
I tried with following code but not working for me,Here is my code

```php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$type = $_POST['type'];    

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"id\":$id,\"type\":\.$type}}",
);
```

Comment: you have a syntax error.

Comment: That would be ["interpolation"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing), not concatenation. Though [`json_encode`ing](http://php.net/json_encode) the real structure would be better.

Answer (score 3):

You can json_encode these fields,

```
$temp = json_encode(['id' => $id, 'type' => $type]);
```

// and pass it to postfields as json encoded string which you are trying to build

```
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $temp
```

Comment: the keys will be `0` and `1` in that case, which negates with what OP actually wants...

Comment: Thanks mate, I made changes.

Comment: Good. And now your answer precisely copies mine :D

Comment: Yeah alias kind, different way.

Comment: @RahulMeshram

How can i encode following line ?

 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"amount\":2,\"currency\":\"KWD\",\"employerid\":\"123\",\"threeDSecure\":true,\"save_card\":false,\"description\":\"Test Description\",\"statement_descriptor\":\"Sample\",\"metadata\":{\"employerid\":$id,\"type\":\"test 2\"},\"reference\":{\"transaction\":\"txn_0001\",\"order\":\"ord_0001\"},\"receipt\":{\"email\":true,\"sms\":true},\"customer\":{\"first_name\":\"test\",\"middle_name\":\"test\",\"last_name\":\"test\",\"full_name\":\"test\",\"email\":\"a@codnostic.com\",\"phone\":{\"country_code\":\"965\"}}"

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to send JSON, you're better off with encoding an array with `json_encode`:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(["id" => $id, "type" => $type])
```

If you check your `"{\"id\":$id,\"type\":\.$type}}"` in a linter, you will see that this json is invalid. The correct json would be `"{\"id\":$id,\"type\":\"$type\"}"`, but as I already said, use `json_encode` instead.

Comment: ,How can i encode following line ?

 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"amount\":2,\"currency\":\"KWD\",\"employerid\":\"123\",\"threeDSecure\":true,\"save_card\":false,\"description\":\"Test Description\",\"statement_descriptor\":\"Sample\",\"metadata\":{\"employerid\":$id,\"type\":\"test 2\"},\"reference\":{\"transaction\":\"txn_0001\",\"order\":\"ord_0001\"},\"receipt\":{\"email\":true,\"sms\":true},\"customer\":{\"first_name\":\"test\",\"middle_name\":\"test\",\"last_name\":\"test\",\"full_name\":\"test\",\"email\":\"a@codnostic.com\",\"phone\":{\"country_code\":\"965\"}}"

Comment: use `json_encode`, Amit. You seem like you do not analyse the answers, but only copy-paste them blindly :-/ Learn from what has already been posted.